# Problema con Python, me sale este error: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

Buenos días, tengo este código y resulta que me da este error cuando compilo

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cuestionario__5.py", line
>   25, in 
>       aa=(a)/(b) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
def myfun(x):
  np.cos(x)/(1+(np.sin(x))**2)
a=myfun(np.pi/3)
b=myfun(np.pi/6)
aa=(a)/(b)
print(aa)
```

¿Sabéis qué es lo que ocurre?

Comment: El np.pi de donde sacas? De una librería?

Comment: Te falta un return a la función. Saludos

Comment: Np que es? y te falta el return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pon correctamente lo imports y haz un return al final.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy

def myfun(x):
  num = np.cos(x)/(1+(np.sin(x))**2)
  return num

a=myfun(np.pi/3)
b=myfun(np.pi/6)
aa=(a)/(b)

print(aa)
```

Comment: oh, muchas gracias :) no me di cuenta

Comment: Para estas cosas utiliza un Lint, si estas empezando. https://www.pylint.org/#install por ejemplo, pero existen mil, te ayuda con los errores. Abrazo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Abrazos.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes dos modos:

```
import numpy as np
# Primer modo: Codigo abreviado
def myfun(x):
  return np.cos(x)/(1+(np.sin(x))**2)

# Segundo Modo: lambda function
myfun = lambda x: np.cos(x)/(1+(np.sin(x))**2)
```

Uso

```
a=myfun(np.pi/3)
b=myfun(np.pi/6)
aa=(a)/(b)

print(aa)
```